# full type of object in python

Tags: python, django, types

I'd like to print the full type of an object

for example:

```
# 1
print full_type(['a','b','c']) # output: "list of str"

# 2
x = book.objects.filter(user=user) # Django Query Set
print full_type(x) # output: "QuerySet of book"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Container objects in Python can contain any type of object, and even mixed types. This is different from statically typed languages where a container must be declared along with the type of object it contains. It doesn't really mean anything to ask what the "full type" of an object is in Python. In other words, the *only* difference between a list instance that contains integers and another instance that contains strings is their contents.

However, if you *really* want a function to print this out, this will do it:

```
def full_type(obj):
    return "%r of " % type(obj) + ','.join('%r' % t for t in set([type(o) for o in obj]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only intend to use it on iterables where every item is the same type, here's a start:

```
In [6]: mylist = ['a','b','c']

In [15]: def full_type(thing):
   ....:     if not hasattr(thing, '__contains__'):
   ....:         return type(thing)
   ....:     else:
   ....:         return '{0} of {1}'.format(type(thing), type(thing[0]))
   ....:     

In [16]: full_type(mylist)
Out[16]: "<type 'list'> of <type 'str'>"
```